# How to find mandatory elements in a variable grouped by another variable?

Tags: sql, oracle, sas

Now I have variable A and variable B. Variable A here acts like a group identifier for variable B. What I want to do now is to find out the groups in A that the 6 mandatory content of B ( which are a, b, c, d, e, f) are not all present in variable B and form a flag. Does anybody know how to make this in SAS or oracle?

My Dataset

[image]

Expected output

[image]

Comment: show us your expected output in tabular format.

Comment: Expected output was updated.

Comment: how are you calculating flag?

Comment: when 6 mandatory content of B ( which are a, b, c, d, e, f) are not all present in variable B then it will flag = 1.

Comment: the blue group got flag = 1 because it just contains a, b, c, d, e and missed f.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This query will give you the group which are having all the given values.

```
SELECT A FROM YOUR_TABLE
WHERE B IN ('a','b','c','d','e','f')
GROUP BY A 
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT B) = 6
```

Then you can get the flag values using multiple ways, one way is to use `LEFT JOIN`

```
SELECT MYTABLE.A,MYTABLE.B, 
CASE WHEN SQ.A IS NOT NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END AS FLAG 
FROM YOUR_TABLE MYTABLE 
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT A FROM YOUR_TABLE
    WHERE B IN ('a','b','c','d','e','f')
    GROUP BY A 
    HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT B) = 6
) SQ ON MYTABLE.A=SQ.A
```

Answer (score 0):

A count distinct aggregate over a filtering case statement will compute the state needed for flag assignment.

```
data have;
  infile cards missover;
  length A B $4;
  input A @;
  do while (1);
    input B @;
    if missing(B) then leave;
    output;
  end;
datalines;
1 a b c d e f d h 
2 a b c d e f g 
3 a b c d e h
;

proc sql;
  create table want as
  select a, b,
    count (distinct 
      case
        when b in ('a','b','c','d','e','f') then b
      end 
    ) ne 6 as flag
  from have
  group by a;
quit;
```